# Substracting the last element form a list of lists

Tags: python

I need to subtract the last element and buid a vector like `[1,1,1,...]`. I have this function:

```
def vectores(lista):
    r=[]
    for e in lista:
        r.append(e[2])
        return r
```

where

```
lista = [['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ['caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

But the function is returning `[1]`; what can I do?

Comment: Has to do with where the scope of the return statement is. In your case, the return is in the for-loop, so on the first itertion it returns the item read

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're returning on the first iteration of your loop. Move the return statement *outside* the `for`-loop:

```
def vectores(lista):
    r=[]
    for e in lista:
        r.append(e[2])
    return r  # here
```

Or just use a list comprehension:

```
def vectores(lista):
    return [e[2] for e in lista]
```